# Explanation of part of a Open Leontief proof

Tags: matrices

This question is from my notes on Open Leontief Models. It talks about the consumption matrix C (a square matrix). All entries are less than 1 (in abs terms) and if the sum of each column is less than 1, then C is called a productive consumption matrix. (Every department "contributes") The theorem is to show that $(I-C)^{-1}$ also has only positive entries. Part of the proof relies on the necessary fact that $C^n→0$ for $n→$ infinity. This is to be shown without the use of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. My book says to assume the largest entry in $C$ to be $a$ and the largest column-sum to be $b$. Prove that the largest entry of $C^n$ is always less than $ab^{n-1}$ How do you do that in a layman's method? Any suggestions/explanation = welcome

Comment: the entries of $C$ are non-negative, I guess?

Comment: an entry could be zero...

Answer (score 2):

Let $c_{ij}$ be the entries of $C\in \mathbb R^{m,m}$. We know $0\le c_{ij}\le a$ for all $i,j$. Moreover, 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m c_{ij} \le b<1
$$
for $i$.

The proof is by induction on $n$. The induction start $n=1$ is trivial.

Denote by $c_{ij,n}$ the $(i,j)$-entry of $C^n$. Note that all entries of $C^n$ are non-negative.

Now assume that for some $n$, the largest entry of $C^n$ is less than $ab^{n-1}$. Then the $(i,j)$-entry of $C^{n+1}$ can be estimated as
$$
0\le c_{ij,n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^m c_{ik,n}c_{kj}
\le ab^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^m c_{kj}\le ab^{n-1} \cdot b = ab^n,
$$
which is the claim.

---

Now for $n\to \infty$ it follows that $C^n\to0$ since $0\le b<1$.

Comment: Ok I need to spend a little time on your answer to let it sink in. My work is demanding my attention. Thanks for the prompt answer...